# How to access a single data from web services with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services, parsing

my teacher gave me this technical specification to access a single data from web services... can you give me an example script to solve this issue...

```
Data    Value
URL http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8000/sourcedata/get_json/client/ID

Method  :   POST 
User_id :   an_user
Password    :   a_password

Request Body:
{
"ID": "1171", 
"user_id": "an_user" , 
"password": "a_password",
"ip_user": "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
}

Request Header  Accept = application/json
Content-Type = application/json
```

Comment: `$_POST['id']` That should get you satarted

Comment: What exactly is your issue?

Comment: Please leave out your storry, describe what you did so far and create a post worty for a knowledge base.